# How to export data to specific rows and columns in XL file from Mathematica?

Tags: export, excel

I have an `XL` File with data like :

```
  {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

That `XL` file name as "MySheet1".

I want to

1. change {2,2} position value(5 to 11).
2. change entire Third row.

for that purpose I tryed with `Export` still not get it.

can anybody help me?

Comment: did you (say) look in the docs at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
a = Import["xl.xls"];
a[[1, 2, 2]] = 11;
a[[1, 3]] = {10, 20, 30};
Export["xl.xls",a];
```